# Clicking outside of Phonegap/Cordova InAppBrowser

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

So I'm making a phonegap/cordova application (v 3.1.0) and need to open the InAppBrowser which doesn't cover the full layout, so I can make custom toolbars and such show beneath the browser. I've managed to make the InAppBrowser appear smaller than the screen by fiddling with the layout options and can succesfully show the toolbars but I'm not able to click on them. Now I need some help on how to manage to get those clicks propagate to the main phonegap view from the inappbrowser.

As for the code - you edit the InAppBrowser.java at the following lines to your desired height:

```
inAppWebView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

And

```
lp.height = HEIGHT;
lp.width = WIDTH;
```

Any ideas on how to pass the click, for example on the blue Close div?

Here's a screenshot to show more detail:
[image]

**EDIT:**

Managed to get some click events by setting an onclick/touch listener on the inAppBrowser WebView, doing the samo on the main view attached on to the dialog created registers no touch events at all.

Also you can find the source code of the inAppBrowser plugin on github on [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/src/android/InAppBrowser.java).